# Get the min and max value of several items with Comparable

Tags: java

I am trying to get the records with  `min distance, min speed and max speed` in the result of my query. Currently I am getting the shortest distance but I am facing problem to get the min and max speed and I am asking myself whether it is possible to add another `public int compareTo(BehaviourItem otherItem)` method in the `BehaviourItem` class to reach that but I am getting the error  `Duplicate method compareTo(BehaviourItem) in type BehaviourItem`.

How can I get the min and max speed from the `BehaviourItem` class?

**Code:**

```
         PreparedStatement prepared = con
                 .prepareStatement("SELECT speed, stop_distance from behaviour where mac = ? and stop_name = ?");
                 prepared.setString(1, macD);
                 prepared.setString(1, sto_nam);
                 ResultSet rsBehav = prepared.executeQuery();
                 List<BehaviourItem> behavList = new ArrayList<BehaviourItem>();
                 while (rsBehav.next()) {
                     int distance = rsBehav.getInt("stop_distance");
                     int speed = rsBehav.getInt("speed");
                     BehaviourItem behItem = new BehaviourItem(distance, speed);
                     behavList.add(behItem);

                 }
                 Collections.sort(behavList);
                 int minDistance =  behavList.get(0).getDistance();
```

**BehaviourItem class:**

```
public class BehaviourItem implements Comparable<BehaviourItem>{
    int speed;
    int distance;

    public BehaviourItem(int speed, int distance) {
        super();
        this.speed = speed;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public int getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(int distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(BehaviourItem otherItem) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Integer.compare(this.distance, otherItem.distance);
    }

}
```

Comment: you could create custom `Comparator`s and pass them to `Collection.sort` method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not let `BehaviourItem` implement `Comparable` as it doesn’t have a *natural order*. Instead, implement different [`Comparator`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for the different properties.

Note that in Java 8, you can implement such a `Comparator` simply as

```
Comparator<BehaviourItem> orderBySpeed=Comparator.comparingInt(BehaviourItem::getSpeed);
```

which is the equivalent of

```
Comparator<BehaviourItem> orderBySpeed=new Comparator<BehaviourItem>() {
    public int compare(BehaviourItem a, BehaviourItem b) {
        return Integer.compare(a.getSpeed(), b.getSpeed());
    }
};
```

or

```
Comparator<BehaviourItem> orderByDistance
                         =Comparator.comparingInt(BehaviourItem::getDistance);
```

for the other property.

Almost every collection method using an order has an overload supporting to pass a `Comparator` to define the order instead of using the natural order:

```
Collections.sort(behavList, orderBySpeed);
```

resp.

```
Collections.sort(behavList, orderByDistance);
```

---

You can even create the comparator ad-hoc:

```
Collections.sort(behavList, Comparator.comparingInt(BehaviourItem::getDistance));
```

and

```
Collections.sort(behavList, Comparator.comparingInt(BehaviourItem::getSpeed));
```

but the stream API allows you to look for minimum or maximum even without sorting:

```
Optional<BehaviourItem> minBySpeed=behavList.stream()
                       .max(Comparator.comparingInt(BehaviourItem::getSpeed));
```

Comment: how can I return the both item here in this method compare(BehaviourItem otherItem1, BehaviourItem otherItem2)? and where can I put that `Comparator<BehaviourItem> orderBySpeed=Comparator.comparingInt(BehaviourItem::getSpeed);`?

Comment: You can place the variable where you want, you can make it a `static` variable of `BehaviourItem` if you think that it will be used often, but you can also place it right before the use and, as said, you can even create the comparator ad-hoc, passing it to the `sort` (or `max`) method without the need for the variable at all.

Answer (score 1):

`Comparable` basically defines an object that has a natural order (e.g. numbers) and thus there can be only one  `compareTo()` method.

For getting min/max for one value you can use a sorted collection, e.g. a list, and access the first and last elements.

However, since your BehaviourItem doesn't have a *natural* order (would it be according to speed or distance?), you'd have to define the order based on the situation. That's where a `Comparator` comes into play: when you want to sort by speed you use a comparator that compares speed, if you want to sort by distance you use a comparator for the distance etc.

Of course if speed and distance change a lot and you always need to get min/max for both you can also just iterate over all items and select min/max the classic way.

Another option, since you're using a query anyways, might be to directly add `min(speed), max(speed)` etc. This would either require a separate query or be added to each result row which in turn might reduce query speed but if you only get a few rows it might still be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define another `compareTo()` function in your `BehaviourItem` class , but you can create custom comparators and use that to sort the list.

An example of a custom comparator -

```
public class BehaviourItem implements Comparable<BehaviourItem>{
    .
    .
    .

    @Override
    public int compareTo(BehaviourItem otherItem) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Integer.compare(this.distance, otherItem.distance);
    }

    static class BehaviourItemComparator implements Comparator<BehaviourItem>
    {            
         public int compare(BehaviourItem b1, BehaviourItem b2)
         {
             return Integer.compare(b1.getSpeed(), b2.getSpeed());
         }
     }

}
```

Then you can use it as -

```
Collections.sort(behavList, BehaviourItem.BehaviourItemComparator)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Comparator` instead of `Comparable`.

You can define as many number of ordering behavior as you want.